# select data from mysql, order it and display based on date of expiry

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to display document name and expiry date in order of expiry date in my browser. Mysql table name is employee_doc and the database name is employee_info. Here is my code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">

<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $dbname = 'employee_info';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    if(! $conn ) 
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    } 

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `employee_doc` ORDER BY `COL 2` ASC';

    $retval = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if(! $retval ) 
    {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC))  
    {
        echo $row['COL 1'];
        echo "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp";
        echo $row['COL 2'];
        echo "<br><br>";
    }  

    mysqli_close($conn); 
?>
```

COL 1 has passport numbers and COL2 has the expiry dates. The problem is that the documents are displayed based only on the first digit of the day. That too it starts from '10' and then echoes to '11'. It doesn't take into account that days start from 1,2,3....then 10. It also doesn't consider month and year. This is how the documents are ordered and printed: 10/5/2025 -  10/8/2018 - 11/2/2020 - 12/10/2016 - 12/2/2021 - 14/06/2021 -  02/4/2017 -  20/02/2023 -   21/02/2025 -  22/07/2019 -  29/10/2024 -  30/03/2019 - 31/05/2021 -  05/1/2023 -  06/11/2017 - 07/3/2020 -   07/4/2018 -  08/11/2025 -  09/7/2023  and so on. Kindly help me correct the code. Thanks...

Comment: You have actual columns called `COL 1` and `COL 2`? Why on earth would you do such a thing? And you should be using MySQL's [`DATE` type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) for this. Not `VARCHAR` or whatever you have currently.

Comment: Is there a way to reverse DATE type from 0000-00-00 to 00-00-0000?Also what's wrong with having columns called COL1 and COL2. I know I am missing the point. Can you kindly elaborate? Thanks.... @Mike

Comment: You should just name the `COL 2` column `expiry_date` in your database, it makes your life easier :) As for your date output: `date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['COL 2']));`

Comment: You tagged this question with [php]. Format the date however you like using PHP, not MySQL. And the reason I asked why you would have those column names is because 1) even though it's valid, you shouldn't put spaces in your column names and 2) because `COL 1` and `COL 2` does not give any indication whatsoever of what those columns are about. Name them accordingly. If you want an expiry date, call it something like `expiry_date` or `ExpiryDate` or whatever.